# External Display feature testing in Emulator JBMR1

Tags: android, android-emulator, external-display

I have downloaded Jelly Bean MR1 SDK in eclipse and wanted to see External Display feature.
In Emulator,

- I enabled Secondary display in "Simulate secondary displays" feature in Development Settings
     => It created Overlay #1
- I used the API Demo->App->Activity->Presentation , but Only "Display # 0 , Built in Screen" is showing up.
      Overlay is shown but nothing is rendered in that. Ideally, I expected images to come in Overlay.

How to test this External Display(Presentation Class) feature in emulator .. Please help.

Thanks and regards
Purush

Comment: Hi Purush, I am having the same issue, have you got any workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: The answer below worked for me. I dont know why it isnt accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution, you need to enable graphics acceleration when starting the emulator, so just pass "-gpu on" when calling emulator.